# Use of global dictionary to create variables

Tags: python, variables, numpy

I need to create an unknown number of python variables, based on a list of file in a folder.

I found that I could use the global dictionary to create and initialize those variables:

```
# libraries import
import os.path
import glob
import numpy as np

# list of all the text files in the folder
list = glob.glob("*.txt")

# creation of the variables based on the name of each file
for file in list:
    shortname = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    globals()[shortname] = np.loadtxt(file)
```

However, I was wondering if it was a good practice to access the global dictionary for variable assignment in python (when we do not know the number and name of the variables in advance) or if there was an alternative method preferable.

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: It's best to not use 'list' as a variable name. It will hide the builtin list.

Comment: How do you plan on accessing these variables later, given that you don't have their names in advance? Also through a call to globals()? Why not just use a regular dictionary?

Comment: @benw yes, I was planning to access those variables also through a call to globals(), basically via the same loop. I didn't want to use a regular dictionary since I will have to calculate basic statistics on them (mean, confidence interval, etc), and creating numpy arrays was more convenient for that.

Comment: Using a dict doesn't stop you from taking advantage of numpy arrays.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks, very useful, I effectively need to move up a level.

Comment: @wim this point was indeed not very clear for me, but it is now thanks to all the answers and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a dedicated dictionary for this:

```
files = {f: np.loadtxt(f) for f in glob.glob("*.txt")}
```

Generally, you should not mix data and variable or attribute names.  Your code could shadow just any Python built-in if a file with the same name exists.

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. I just made a slight modification of the code, to not have the ".txt" in the variable name: files = {f[:-4]: np.loadtxt(f) for f in glob.glob("*.txt")}

Comment: @gcalmettes: instea of doing `f[:-4]` you could use `os.path.splitext` to separate the extension. Not that it matters, but it feels neater to me.

Answer (score 2):

No, you probably shouldn't be using globals for this. Instead, create a dictionary or class and store the values in that.